# tmux cannot adjust pane height on mac

Tags: macos, tmux

my tmux on mac can only adjust pane width by using  (Left or Right)
but if I try to adjust the pane height by using  (Up or Down), it just dose not work, it only change the focus of the pane.

I tried to rm the ~/.tmux.conf and ~/.bashrc, but it doesn't work as well.

my system is mac osx 10.12

any idea, guys?